# What does this Perl syntax mean?

Tags: perl, syntax, dictionary, split

I have one line of code in a pretty massive perl program that I don't understand.

```
map {$cycle{$_}=1} split(/\s*,\s*/,$cycle);
```

$cycle is a string, and there is my %cycle declared above this line. I get that the "split" part separates the string into it's elements, but what are the s and the slashes for in the second part, and I don't understand the first half at all. 
The first half is the really confusing part, what happens to all the elements of that split string?
I've never used Perl before. Thanks for any explanation you can give

Comment: you can bind a name in different contexts in perl, for instance you can have `$cycle`, `@cycle`, and `%cycle`. From this example there must be a hash named cycle declared above this map statement. (hashes are declared with the `%` sigil)

Comment: there is a hash declared above it! I'll add an edit mentioning that, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a misuse of `map`.

Adding some whitespace it looks like

```
map {
    $cycle{$_} = 1
} split /\s*,\s*/, $cycle;
```

So `$cycle` is being split at the commas, including any spaces that may precede or follow it, and the corresponding element of `%cycle` is set to 1 for each item from the `split`

It should be written

```
$cycle{$_} = 1 for split /\s*,\s*/, $cycle;
```

or perhaps

```
for ( split /\s*,\s*/, $cycle ) {
    $cycle{$_} = 1;
}
```

And if you know who wrote the original code then please give them a slap from me.

Comment: but how does %cycle have any elements in it to correspond to? The only time it's included is one line saying my %cycle

Comment: The keys and values comes to life when they are added to the hash.  You don't need to define or describe the hash in great detail before it can be used.

Answer (score 2):

`split`'s first parameter is a regular expression used to define what separates the items to return. It is traditionally provided to `split` as a match operator.

```
/.../
```

is match operator. It's the short form of

```
m/.../
```

However,

```
split /.../, ....
```

and

```
split m/.../, ....
```

actually behave as

```
split qr/.../, ....
```

`qr/.../` compiles the regex pattern within and returns the compiled form in a scalar.

Operators including `m//` and `qr//` are documented in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).

---

As a regex pattern,

```
\s*,\s*
```

signifies zero or more whitespace characters (`\s*`), followed by a comma, followed by zero or more whitespace characters.

Regular expressions are documented in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

---

The `map` is used to perform a foreach loop. When the values it returns are ignored

```
map BLOCK LIST
```

is just a weird way of writing

```
for (LIST) BLOCK
```

so

```
map { $cycle{$_} = 1 } split(/\s*,\s*/, $cycle);
```

is the same as

```
$cycle{$_} = 1 for split(/\s*,\s*/, $cycle);
```

or

```
for (split(/\s*,\s*/, $cycle)) {
   $cycle{$_} = 1;
}
```

or

```
for my $val (split(/\s*,\s*/, $cycle)) {
   $cycle{$val} = 1;
}
```

A more appropriate use of map would have been

```
my %cycle = map { $_ => 1 } split(/\s*,\s*/, $cycle);
```

which is equivalent to

```
my @anon;
for (split(/\s*,\s*/, $cycle)) {
   push @anon, $_ => 1;
}
my %cycle = @anon;
```

though the following is more efficient:

```
my %cycle; ++$cycle{$_} for split(/\s*,\s*/, $cycle);
```

[`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html)

Comment: `split` far predates `qr//`.

Comment: Or to avoid loops, `my @anon = split(/\s*,\s*/, $cycle);
my %cycle; @cycle{@anon} = (1) x @anon;`